# Solr, Tomcat 7 on windows Server 2008 (64 bit), admin screens return 404

Tags: tomcat, windows-server-2008, solr

I'm not sure if this belongs here or on super user.

We have set up Tomcat 7 on our server and have configured Solr.  We can go to localhost/solr and localhost/solr/admin, but on the admin screen when we click "configure" or "schema" we get a 404 error for "/solr/admin/file/?file=solrconfig.xml"

We tried entering the url /solr/admin/get-file.jsp?file=solrconfig.xml and we get an access denied.

Our solr home, as shown on our admin page, is c:\solr.  We have granted "everyone" full control to this folder (and verified the xml files have this permission) and yet it still errors.

We have tried putting bin and conf in the webapps\solr folder and that didn't help.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: I'd try http://serverfault.com for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out it is a bug in the solr implementation.  There is an extra "/" in the url which causes the 404 error.  If you remove it, so the url looks like

> /solr/admin/file?file=solrconfig.xml

instead of

> /solr/admin/file/?file=solrconfig.xml

the error goes away.  Hope this helps someone else.